# How to convert a List<Map<String, dynamic>> inside a Map<String, dynamic> to JSON in Dart?

Tags: arrays, json, dart, flutter

I'm trying to send a `Map<String, dynamic>`, and one of the `dynamic` is actually a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`.

I assemble it like that :

```dart
Packet packet = Packet(
  datas: stocks.map((stock) => stock.toJson()).toList(),
);

String json = jsonEncode(packet);
```

The problem is what's being sent is actually this :

```
{
    "datas": {
        "rows": "[{NoArticle: 051131626638, Description: Ruban pour tapis, qty: 5}]"
    }
}
```

The expected output is this :

```
{
    "datas": {
        "rows": [{
            "NoArticle": "051131626638",
            "Description": "Ruban pour tapis",
            "qty": 5,
        }]
    }
}
```

I want to send a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`, not a `String`. How do I do that?

Comment: Hello, NatoBoram. What is the expected output? `datas` should contain a list of objects, is that it?

Comment: Also, is `stocks` the list you're referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer : I am a dumbass.

I passed the parameter trough a function, like this :

```dart
Server.send("sendInventoryBatch", {
  "rows": "${stocks.map((stock) => stock.toJson()).toList()}",
});
```

Of course it would return a String.

Question is invalid. If you have a similar problem, please open a different question. Sorry for the inconvenience.

---

Now if anyone actually has this question and stumbles upon this thread, here's how to do it :

1. Assemble your object, and make sure you didn't stringify it along the way
2. Use `jsonEncode`

In case of doubt, make everything a `Map<String, dynamic>`, a `List<dynamic>`, or a sub-class of those two first.

```
Packet packet = Packet(
  appType: "inventoryManager",
  module: "",
  action: action,
  datas: data,
  deviceID: Globals.map["UUID"],
  cbackid: cback,
);
```

You can generate classes like my custom `Packet` from JSON using multiple online resources because `jsonEncode` will use the auto-generated `Map<String, dynamic> toJson()`.

- https://app.quicktype.io/ - Was recommended to me on [Discord](https://discord.gg/jZMQDeX) by [Miyoyo#5957](https://canary.discordapp.com/channels/420324994703163402/421445316617961502/545687444188692480)
- https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/ - I used this one before
- http://json2dart.com/

```dart
String json = jsonEncode(packet);
```

And voilà, you're done.

Answer (score -1):

Did you look at packages `json_serializable`?
Here's an example of a `Person` that has many `Order`s : [example](https://github.com/dart-lang/json_serializable/blob/master/example/lib/example.dart)

```dart
    // Copyright (c) 2015, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
    // for details. All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a
    // BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

    import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

    part 'example.g.dart';

    @JsonSerializable()
    class Person {
      final String firstName;
      @JsonKey(includeIfNull: false)
      final String middleName;
      final String lastName;

      @JsonKey(name: 'date-of-birth', nullable: false)
      final DateTime dateOfBirth;

      @JsonKey(name: 'last-order')
      final DateTime lastOrder;

      @JsonKey(nullable: false)
      List<Order> orders;

      Person(this.firstName, this.lastName, this.dateOfBirth,
          {this.middleName, this.lastOrder, List<Order> orders})
          : orders = orders ?? <Order>[];

      factory Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$PersonFromJson(json);

      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PersonToJson(this);
    }

    @JsonSerializable(includeIfNull: false)
    class Order {
      int count;
      int itemNumber;
      bool isRushed;
      Item item;

      @JsonKey(
          name: 'prep-time',
          fromJson: _durationFromMilliseconds,
          toJson: _durationToMilliseconds)
      Duration prepTime;

      @JsonKey(fromJson: _dateTimeFromEpochUs, toJson: _dateTimeToEpochUs)
      final DateTime date;

      Order(this.date);

      factory Order.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$OrderFromJson(json);

      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$OrderToJson(this);

      static Duration _durationFromMilliseconds(int milliseconds) =>
          Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds);

      static int _durationToMilliseconds(Duration duration) =>
          duration.inMilliseconds;

      static DateTime _dateTimeFromEpochUs(int us) =>
          DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(us);

      static int _dateTimeToEpochUs(DateTime dateTime) =>
          dateTime.microsecondsSinceEpoch;
    }

    @JsonSerializable()
    class Item {
      int count;
      int itemNumber;
      bool isRushed;

      Item();

      factory Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ItemFromJson(json);

      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ItemToJson(this);
    }

    @JsonLiteral('data.json')
    Map get glossaryData => _$glossaryDataJsonLiteral;
```

Comment: Hello, John. It's important to add the important part of the code itself in here, instead of just posting the link.